# Скажите, нужна ли запятая в следующем предложении?

Tags: вводные-слова

Среди прочего(,) общественность была возмущена тем, что...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Среди прочего» как случай устойчивого словосочетания (*при всём том*; *в конечном счёте*; *по традиции*; *в конце концов*, т.е. в итоге) запятыми не выделяют. Лишь иногда  делают это, когда имеют дело с авторским пониманием текста, а именно с особым обстоятельством.